# Rails 3 devise "token per client"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

I want to use devise's tokens to support logging in/out in multiple clients at once. The problem is that today there's only one authentication token per user.

With today's devise i can:
1. Use the same token for all clients.
2. Reset the token on every login (and lose the login on other devices).

What i want i a the ability to create multiple tokens (one for each client). Does devise has that option? Is there any other plugin?

Thanks,

Comment: "multiple clients" - client is a user's device ("user has many clients")?

Comment: What don't you like about your first approach?

Comment: Yup, client is a user's device.

Comment: The first approach creates the same problem as the second b/c when someone will "logout" from his device it'll lose connection in all other devices (the authentication token will be deleted)

Comment: did you implement something already? Or are you just thinking about it?

Comment: I'm thinking about implementing multiple token authentication over devise. Wanted to know if there's any other (already made) solution?

Comment: @Rafa: I'm interested in this too. There is the [OAuth2 library](https://github.com/socialcast/devise_oauth2_providable) but that seems a bit heavy for this scenario. Isn't there some filter we could override?

Comment: I implemented it with redis and a new Devise Strategy. I'll upload a post to my blog soon. www.refaelos.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it and wrote my solution in my blog: http://www.refaelos.com/post/20664288136/multiple-token-authentication-with-devise-redis?2c914400